# Using same column twice, but 1st column dups are removed

Tags: t-sql

I have 2 separate Select Statements. Both of them select PrimaryID, but they also Select columns that aren't shared, like PrimaryID. I am using an Inner Join to get my results back that look like this:

```
PrimaryID | col2 | col3 | PrimaryID | col4 | col5
    1         2      3        1         2      3
    1         3      4        1         3      4
    1         5      6        1         5      6
    2         3      4        2         3      4
    2         5      6        2         5      6
    2         7      8        2         7      8
```

What is wanted is this:

```
PrimaryID | col2 | col3 | PrimaryID | col4 | col5
    1         2      3        1         2      3
                              1         3      4
                              1         5      6
    2         3      4        2         3      4
                              2         5      6
                              2         7      8
```

Is there anyway that I can achieve this? Thanks.

QUERY:

```
Select * from
    (SELECT primaryid, col2, col3
    from g.table
    left join (random stuff)
    WHERE DATEPART(m, CreateDateTime) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
    AND DATEPART(yyyy, CreateDateTime) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))) t1
inner join
    (select primaryid, col4, col5
    from g.table
    where primaryid in (select primaryid from g.table) and col5 = 0) t2
    on t1.primaryid = t2.primaryid
    order by t1.col2
```

Comment: please show us your query. is that a self join? or two tables?

Comment: What business logic dictates when the first three fields (from the first query) should or should not be shown?  And what query gave you the first example set of results?  We need to See what you've tried to have Any hope of fixing it...

Comment: Do you need to display the expected output in some kind of UI or should you result set should be like that ...?

Comment: It appears that you dont want a rowset, but you are thinking 'gimme results like my Excel pivots'. Your example implies you want NULLs in rows 2,3,5, and 6.

Comment: It's all going to be exported to an Excel file via a program that I wrote. I will post some of the query, since it is around 200 lines.

Comment: In almost all cases it is a bad habit to do *display issues* like grouping, aggregates and even column captions *within* your result set. Such things are normally done within your presentation layer (your application)...

Comment: You're right @Shnugo, but I haven't been having luck with finding anything on how to do it via VB.NET

Comment: Just added a replica query to what I am using.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is syntactically not correct, so my suggestion isn't either, but you'll get the idea: Use `ROW_NUMBER` with an `OVER(PARTITION BY ...)` to get numbered sub-sets. Then use `CASE` to force the needed values only in lines where your number is "1". Other lines return an empty string or `NULL`.

Attention: I changed your two identically named `primaryid` columns to `ID1` and `ID2`:

```
WITH Numbered AS
(
    Select *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID1 ORDER BY col2,col3) AS SortNumber
    from
        (SELECT primaryid AS ID1, col2, col3
        from g.table
        left join (random stuff)
        WHERE DATEPART(m, CreateDateTime) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
        AND DATEPART(yyyy, CreateDateTime) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))) t1
    inner join
        (select primaryid AS ID2, col4, col5
        from g.table
        where primaryid in (select primaryid from g.table) and col5 = 0) t2
        on t1.ID1 = t2.ID2
)
SELECT CASE WHEN SortNumber=1 THEN ID1 ELSE '' END AS ID1
      ,CASE WHEN SortNumber=1 THEN col2 ELSE '' END AS col2
      ,CASE WHEN SortNumber=1 THEN col3 ELSE '' END AS col3
      ,ID2,col4,col5
FROM Numbered
```

Comment: What would you do for the Cases down below if primaryID is an incriminating number, starting from 200,000 - 800,000?

Comment: @RockGuitarist1, sorry, did not see this in time... I do not understand what you mean... It is of no importance which values are there. The rows get sorted after the specified column and then are numbered form 1 to n. The *first row* will always have the `SortNumber=1`...

Comment: I ended up fixing this by writing code within the program I am using the Stored Procedure in. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @RockGuitarist1 If you don't mind, it would be very kind of you to close this question as solved (by ticking the acceptance check) and vote on it. On the one side it **is** solved, as there is a working solution to the given issue, on the other side it was me who told you right from the beginning to better solve this in the calling application  :-))